# What Does "User was removed" mean?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

What does this +2 reputation mean?

[image: user was removed]

Comment: This happens on all SO sites. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a user is removed, *all* their votes are removed as well. So this was likely a user that had downvoted you once and that was deleted today, which removed his downvotes as well.

Comment: So can I tell which question was voted on? I didn't see any link (the "user" text links to my reputation page).

Comment: @ike No, votes are considered private information so you don't see exactly on which post the user voted.

Comment: So there is no proof of the previous existence of the aforementioned user. I'll post a question on main about these notable mod's claims. (Although there is an _If_, and an  _likely_). Better don't.